# SQL to group by two rows?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I need a sql query for the below table

```
ID    Name      type     priority
1    French     New       2
2    English    New       3
3    Spanish    New       4
4    Deutch     Old       1
5    Japanese   Old       2
6    Chinese    New       5
7    Monotype   Old       3
8    Hindi      New       6
9    Greek      Old       4
```

I tried ORDER BY *type* and *priority*, output returned looks like this:

```
ID      Name     type     priority
1    French     New       2
2    English    New       3
3    Spanish    New       4
6    Chinese    New       5
8    Hindi      New       6
4    Deutch     Old       1
5    Japanese   Old       2
7    Monotype   Old       3
9    Greek      Old       4
```

I need an output like

```
ID      Name     type     priority
1      French    New      2
4      Deutch    Old      1
```

Can anyone suggest a SQL query for that?

Comment: do you need only first one?

Comment: yes, from type="New" one record and from type="Old" one record based priority order by asc

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.* from table t
  inner join
      (select type, priority from table
       group by  type, priority 
       having priority = MIN(priority)) t2
   on t.type = t2.type and t.priority = t2.priority
```

Comment: by i need priority order by asc

Comment: Why do you think this query will return the two rows - and only the two rows - OP is looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from 
(select top 1 * from Table
where type = 'New'
order by priority asc) New
union
select * from 
(select top 1 * from Table
where type = 'Old'
order by priority asc) Old
```

I thnk, should give you what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of doing this uses the ANSI standard window function `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by priority) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by id;
```

Comment: you should remove `name`.. it should be like  `(partition by type order by priority)`